# ¿Existe forma de cargar contenido html asincrona?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, ajax

Estoy realizando una aplicacion web, en cocreto realizo un wizard de 5 pasos pero demasiados campos, pero el archivo ya se extendio bastante y tarda mucho en cargar, los .js ya estan de manera asincrona, pero el html esta haciendo que tarde en cargar mucho.
¿Existe la manera de cargar los pasos de 2 a 5 de manera asincrona, para evitar dicho retraso?

Comment: ¿Qué tecnología usas en el lado servidor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO puedes cargar HTML5 asincrono, ya que javascript funciona para él.

Lo que puedes hacer es crear código HTML desde Javascript e introducirlo al DOM de manera asincrona, cuando lo necesites.

Ejemplo:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
 setTimeout(()=> {
 document.body.innerHTML = `<h1> Bienvenido </h1> <p>
 Como estás? </p>`;
 }, 1e3 * 2);
});
```

Comment: Ejemplo: Si creas un archivo .php con puro código HTML y después lo cargas desde un controlador mediante una llamada al servidor ajax, se puede cargar HTML de manera asíncrona

Answer (score 0):

Con que tipo de tecnología estas trabajando?

Lo que podrías probar es cargar el código html desde el controlador, activandolo cuando sea necesario prendiendo un parámetro.

**No especifico código** ni, tecnología ya que no has puesto con que trabajas.

Comment: Para el frontend utilizo thymeleaf y en backend spring